# VS 2017 Solution Explorer: Collapse all nodes to a specific depth

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Is there a way to collapse all nodes in the visual studio solution explorer to a specific depth?
I have 4 different projects in the solution explorer, but the most important nodes are in depth 2, and I would like to collapse all nodes to this depth for a better overview.
I know about the "collapse all" function, but that's not exactly what I'm searching for.

Comment: I don't believe this can be done with VS out of the box. The only option is the collapse all function like you mentioned. There is an extension called "Codemaid" that allows you to collapse by project/solution underneath your main solution. If you're interested in that, here's a link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveCadwallader.CodeMaid

Comment: Thanks, I would have prefered not having to use extensions but it looks like something like this is the only solution.
I tried codemaid but didn't find how to do what I wanted but I will look into it further. 
If I find a solution (hopefully) I'll post it here

Comment: You can make a new Explorer View for the specific project

Comment: So that specific folders are opened or what do you mean by new explorer view?
I search and tried to do that but didn't managed to do it. Could you pls tell me how to do what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Even in VS2019 this can not be done out of the box. There is now an extension that does the trick: Collapse Level by MWilski which has quite good reviews.

[CollapseLevel](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mwilski.CollapseLevel)